# Schedule website changes

Tags: php, schedule

I occasionally have to make some changes to a website Monday at 00:00. These are very small amends like changing an image or a word.
The website is built using PHP and doesn't use a database. 
It would be very annoying to have to do it manually in the middle of the night so I am using epoch time and an If statement like so:

```
<img src="/
<?php
$timestamp=time();
if ($timestamp<1433769105) {
    echo "image1.jpg";
}
else {
    echo "image2.jpg";
}
?>
">
```

It does the job but imagine 20 pieces of code like this scattered through a few php files. It doesn't look professional at all. Not mentioning the time spent removing them.

I am looking for an alternative to this approach but I don't seem to come up with anything. I am open to any suggestions.

Comment: You can let a cronjob run at Monday 00:00 and rename the files.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have access to do that but +1 for the answer.

Comment: Use a versioning software like Git https://git-scm.com/ .  Make an account on some like GitHub.  Publish your website in versions.  You can stage your site on your Git repo and then it's just a simple `git pull` to update your site on your server.  There are also other services like CIMs (continuous integration servers) like Jenkins that can be used to schedule build events (events that will automatically pull your latest git repo).

Comment: @Squeegy to run git pull I would need access to the server's console, I only have FTP access to this website. I will try to use git in this way on a different site just to test the concept. Thanks!

Comment: Eventually, you have to develop some mechanism to deploy changes. If you want small footprint of solution, I would use JSON file as ordered array (PHP functions json_encode, json_decode) to store all filenames for concurrent placement and timestamps after which to deploy. First timestamp which applies returns value for position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be beneficial for you to write yourself a deployment service on a separate server that can schedule an FTP upload (using a cron job) at Monday 00:00. You could use a Raspberry Pi for this if you wish to save a bit of money :)

To further elaborate, the server (or Pi) could keep a copy of your new files ready to upload and your FTP information ready to upload to. Then you can write a bash script to upload your new files via the FTP details to your web server.

Then you just create a cron job to run the bash script on Monday 00:00. Sit back and relax knowing your new code will be on your server as long as its online and available to receive files on Monday 00:00 via FTP.

To expand your deployment script, you could then add logging so that you can wake up the next morning and view the logs from the deployment to see if any files were missed or whether anything went wrong.

Hope this helps!

Comment: This makes sense. It will involve some work beforehand but it might just do the trick!

Comment: Yeah especially if you included logging so you could see if anything went wrong. I do however (if you are doing this a lot in the future) recommend switching to using some form of source control (Git) and researching Continuous Deployment from Git.

Answer (score 1):

I'd put a `migrations` folder somewhere and put migrations like

```
<?php
// when the time has come
if (time() > strtotime())
{
    // do the changes you wanted to make
    rename("image1.jpg", "image2.jpg");

    // move this migration into the done folder so 
    // that it doesn't get executed once more
    rename(PHP_SELF, __DIR__."/done/".PHP_SELF);
}
```

You then simply include all files from your migration folder. Each migration then checks if it should be executed.

```
// include all files in migrations
foreach (new DirectoryIterator('migrations') as $script)
{
    if ($script->isFile() && substr($script, -4) === '.php')
        include 'migrations/' . $script;
}
```

**Alternatively** put a date/timestamp into the migration name and have it only execute if the time has come:

`2015-06-09.php` or `1433800800.php`

```
<?php
rename("image1.jpg", "image2.jpg");
```

In your `index.php`

```
// include all files in migrations
foreach (new DirectoryIterator('migrations') as $script)
{
    // only execute *.php files
    if (! $script->isFile() || substr($script, -4) !== '.php')
        continue;

    // extract date
    $date = substr($script, 0, -4);

    // convert string dates to timestamp 
    // if they are not timestamps already
    if (! is_numeric($date))
        $date = strotime($date);

    // time has come? 
    if (time() >= $date)
    {
        require 'migrations/' . $script;

        // move out of migrations folder so that it 
        // doesn't get executed once more
        rename('migrations/' . $script, 'migrations/done/' . $script);
    }
}
```